# System.IO.IOException Eror - Process Can not access file to Read...

Tags: vb.net, io

My website uses adatabase for geoLocating the clients country.

Here is my error code:

```
System.IO.IOException
Inner Exception:
The process cannot access the file 'C:\*****\******\wwwroot\GEO2db\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb' because it is being used by another process.
```

And Here is the code that I run to get the country from the database (it is called in my master page):

```
Public Function GetGeoIPCountry() As String
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Dim ip As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    Dim FileWithPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") & "GEO2db\GeoLite2-Country.mmdb"
    Dim reader = New DatabaseReader(FileWithPath)
    Dim Om = reader.Omni(ip)
    Dim country As String = Om.Country.Name
    reader.Dispose()
    Return country
End Function
```

Comment: Try to set 'reader' variable to Nothing, after the dispose, or directly use an "Using" Block...

Comment: The DatabaseReader implements the IDisposable Interface, so I guess it would be better to put it within a Using Block, as your reader is not being 'disposed' or 'closed' properly

Comment: Just check if you don't have a database service running in background which is connected and accessing the database while you trying to use you program. If the table is opened in Database Management Tool, program might not get access

Comment: No, I never connect to this database in any way other than the website doing it.

The question is, is it possible that 2 users connect at the same time could cause this error?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that this error does not happen all the time, only randomly